# What is the time complexity of stream filter obtained from HashSet?

Tags: java, performance, data-structures, java-stream, hashset

```
Set<Integer> set = new HashSet<>();
set.add(1);
set.add(2);
...
```

what is the time complexity of below operation? O(n) or O(1)?

```
set.stream().filter(e -> e == 1).findFirst();
```

Comment: I'd strongly suggest not to rely on unboxing in such cases. Your comparison is equivalent to `e.intValue() == 1`, which is fine. In a similar case, I can't recall exactly anymore, boxing happened instead, so I was comparing two objects using `==` instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can understand it better if you see it from another side, your solution is same like this :

```
for(Integer i : set){
    if(i == 1){
        break;
    }
}
```

**So it is `O(n)`** because it loop over all the set, and check one by one, if the condition is correct return the value else continue until `n` elsement

Answer (score 1):

It's O(n) - **after you create a `Stream` instance, you are no longer operating on a `HashSet`**, but on a `Stream` that goes over all elements of the source `Set`.

It's a lazy linear sequence where all elements are visited one by one - hence O(n)